# Is it possible to add a add a number after select a value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I trying to add +1 in a column after select but its not working, what I want is, when I make a search, the scripts adds +1 in a column to track how much searches I did.

Heres how it is now

```
$QUERY = "SELECT company FROM test WHERE number = '$number[0]' LIMIT 1";
```

And I want to add this

```
UPDATE users SET consultas=consultas+1 WHERE username = '$username'
```

If I add another `$QUERY` line the script breaks, any ideas ?

Comment: You cannot. You have to do that somewhere manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nature, SELECT queries are for returning information from the database, not updating the database. To this end, triggers aren't even available for SELECT queries to react to the action. As such, if you want to increment a value, this must be done in a separate query, as an UPDATE query or possibly an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query if that better suits your needs.

Comment: yeah but adding another query line wont work, it breaks the code, I'm not creating the code, just changing so I dont know how to do it.

Comment: heres the whole part

      $QUERY = "SELECT company FROM test WHERE number = '$number[0]' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysql_query($QUERY);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      if(is_array($row))

Comment: You will be able to send a second query as a separate transaction.  For instance, after what you have now you could send an UPDATE query. Alternatively, you could look into [mysqli multiqueries](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), though it's a step up in complexity and moving to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) would be better for good habits. Edit: Ah, just noticed you're using mysql_~ functions.  You should consider updating these as they're deprecated. [See here](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Oh thanks, it solved, btw, I'll try do update it to see if it gets faster.

Comment: I fixed adding another query with result and row:
      $QUERY = "UPDATE users SET consultas=consultas+1 WHERE username = '$username'";
      $result = mysql_query($QUERY);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);   
      $QUERY = "SELECT company FROM portados  WHERE number = '$number[0]' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysql_query($QUERY);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: That looks about right given what you were wanting to accomplish. I would encourage you to also look into updating the code to a supported API (mysqli or PDO), especially if you're tasked with maintaining this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute those as two separate queries. Also, be *very* careful to ensure your data is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because it looks like you've forgotten to do that.

Be sure to check the result code of each as an error may occur at any time. If you use PDO there's a fairly robust [error handling pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) you can follow.